# How to stop subfolder redirect to root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I have website hosted in root folder and the root folder is pointing to http://www.example.com and i have subfolder in root /upload which is pointing to www.upload.com

Now when i am using

```
RewriteBase /

Redirect 302 /index.html http://www.example.com/index.php
```

Now both **example.com/index.html** is redirected to **example.com/index.php**

and **upload.com/index.html** is redirected **example.com/index.php**

How can i avoid **upload.com/index.html** redirection to **example.com/index.php**

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid this redirection using a Redirect directive, You need to use mod-rewrite with conditions,

Try the following code in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
#IF http_host=="www.example.com"#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
#redirect "/index.html" to "/index.php"#
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [NC,L,R,NE]
```